# Is it possible to cast an object as 2 different things within the same method?

Tags: java

Apologies if this is worded poorly or search-able, I couldn't find anything on it and I'm almost exclusively self taught.

I have an `Entity` class and multiple subclasses, `Building` and `Creature` being the relevant ones here.

I have a `setTarget(Entity e)` method that I'd like to use for both the `Building` and the `Creature` classes because at this level they are identical.

I'm wondering if it's possible to cast e to either a `Building` or a `Creature` depending on which type it is, rather than creating 2 whole methods with the same code.

```
private void setTarget(Entity e) {
    if (e.getType.equals("Creature")) {
        Creature c = (Creature)e; //rest of code assumes c is now a creature rather than a building
    }
}
```

I realise I could do this by putting the target mechanics in the `Entity` class but then that code would be irrelevant to all the other subclasses that do not have/need targets.

Any help or tips would be very much appreciated, thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I looked into instanceof and it definitely cleans up the code a bit but nobody understood what I meant;

```
private void setTarget(Entity e) {
    if (e instanceof Creature) {
        Creature c = (Creature)e;
    } else if (e instanceof Building) {
        Building c = (Building)e;
    }
    //Building OR Creature code here ie;
    c.setTarget();
}
```

Is this achievable?

Comment: Looks like you want a Factory Pattern. If you're using polymorphism, this can easily be achieved.

Comment: Why have you put all that code on a single line?  It's impossible to read.

Comment: You can use `e.getClass().equals(Creature.class)` or `e instanceof Creature` in your `if` statement.

Comment: `if(o instanceof Building){Building b=(Building)o;}else if(o instanceof Creature){Creature c=(Creature)o;}`

Comment: Why don't you simply define two setTarget() methods, one taking a Creature, and one taking a Building? It would be much simpler, and the users of your class wouldn't make the false assumption that the target can be any Entity.

Comment: I edited the OP to better explain my question(including  the instanceof method)

Comment: Response to title only: *"Is it possible to cast an object as 2 different things within the same method?"* Yes, e.g. the Java Scripting framework provides [`ScriptEngine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html) objects, which may also implement [`Compilable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/Compilable.html) and [`Invocable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/Invocable.html). As such, a method working with a `ScriptEngine` may also cast it to both `Compilable` and `Invocable`, being all 3 at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Java keyword `instanceof` or `getClass()`. The difference between these two is that if, say, a class `SmallBuilding` subclasses `Building`, then `mySmallBuilding instanceof Building` will return true, whereas `mySmallBuilding.getClass().equals` `(Building.class)` will return false, because calling `getClass()` on a `SmallBuilding` will return a different `Class` object than a `Building`'s class. Having said that, it is usually advisable to use `instanceof` in subclass-dependent programs like yours, and `getClass()` in, for example, writing an `equals()` method (Since both objects must be of the same class). Here is an example of how that would work:

```
private void setTarget(Entity e) {
    if (e instanceof Creature) {
        Creature c = (Creature)e;
        // Creature-specific code here
    } else if (e instanceof Building) {
        Building b = (Building)e;
        // Building-specific code here
    }
    // Could add an else for other Entity subclasses (might throw UnsupportedOperationException)
}
```

Edit: Based on the edit you made to your question, you could do something like this:

```
private void setTarget(Entity e) {
    if (e instanceof Creature) {
        Creature c = (Creature)e;
        c.setTarget();
    } else if (e instanceof Building) {
        Building b = (Building)e;
        b.setTarget();
    }
    // Could add an else for other Entity subclasses (might throw UnsupportedOperationException)
}
```

You *do* have to have the `setTarget()` in both `if` statements. Another option would be to define an interface for `setTarget()`, like so:

```
public interface Targetable {
    public void setTarget();
}
```

And then  have `Building` and `Creature` impliment `Targetable`. You could then define `setTarget()` as:

```
private void setTarget(Targetable t) {
    t.setTarget();
}
```

Or:

```
private void setTarget(Entity e) {
    if (t instanceof Targetable) {
        ((Targetable)t).setTarget();
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay instance of, is definitely a nicer way of doing it than the way I am currently using, thank you.

Comment: @Flash Made an edit that I think will greatly help you with your problem.

Comment: I've never used an interface before but it looks like what I want to be doing, I'll look into how they work! Thanks so much! Sorry for not knowing this stuff yet

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need to differentiate between `Creature` and `Building`?

I would probably create an interface `Targetable` (or something with a better name) that contains the method `setTarget()` and is implemented by `Creature` and `Building`.

This way in your method `setTarget(Entity e)` you don't need to query for `Creature` and `Building` (and maybe even more classes in the future) but you only check for `e instanceof Targetable`, cast it to this interface type and run `setTarget()` on it.

Note: The need of using `instanceof` and casting is often an indication that your code is not structured in an optimal way…

Comment: @Majora320: Haha, looks like `Targetable` is a good idea, if we both came to it independently ;-) I'll still keep my answer, maybe it helps someone understanding better because of the different wording. Even if it does not help it does not hurt :-P

Comment: Both you and @Majora320 think implementing an interface is the way to go so I'm looking into that. I've been following youtube tutorials that unfortunately never seem to finish and tried to continue on without them. So yeah, my code probably isn't structured too optimally but I don't know what I can do about that.

Comment: @Flash: You could post your code to [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) and get useful feedback on how you can make your code cleaner.

Comment: Is it better to do that early on in development or when I have a more established program?

Comment: @Flash: I would say it is better early in the development because then it is still easier to adjust the global structure/architecture of your application. The code you are posting there should be working though. See [the help page on Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more information.

Comment: The code I wrote doesn't work, it can't resolve c. I'll sort this out then post my code over there, Thanks again!